# Restricting preprocessing-numbers in a C preprocessor to only handle valid floating and integer constants

Tags: c, syntax, c-preprocessor, standards

I'm currently implementing a C11 compiler and I'm aiming to integrate the preprocessor into the rest compiler and not have it as a stand-alone component. As such, the preprocessor can safely assume that its output will be valid in the following stages.

Reading about the preprocessing number token, it seems like it only exists to simplify the implementation of a stand-alone preprocessor. Simplifying the format of numbers, it doesn't have to handle the full complexity of numeral expressions. Quoting the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html):

> The purpose of this unusual definition is to isolate the preprocessor from the full complexity of numeric constants. It does not have to distinguish between lexically valid and invalid floating-point numbers, which is complicated.

As the preprocessor will be integrated to the rest of the compiler framework, this is not an issue for me.

In section 6.4.8.4 [Preprocessing numbers; Semantics] of the C11 standard, it claims

> A preprocessing number does not have type or a value; it acquires both after a successful conversion (as part of translation phase 7) to a floating constant token or an integer constant token.

So it seems like every preprocessing-number will be converted into a floating or integer constant later on in the compilation process. I cannot find any other references to preprocessing-numbers in the standard, so it seems like this is their only purpose, but I may be wrong.

My question is, would it be valid for the preprocessor to restrict preprocessing-numbers to only valid integer and floating point constants? Or are there cases where having such a restriction would cause otherwise valid programs to fail?

Comment: What PP-numbers aren't valid integer or floating point constants?

Comment: [this](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4p5) ? `The program fragment 1Ex is parsed as a preprocessing number token (one that is not a valid floating or integer constant token),` But it's odd, because in [`pp-number` syntax](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.8p1) sign is _not_ optional.

Comment: @Barmar `0x2x3` and `34.2.8` are a valid pp-numbers, but not a valid integer or floating constants. pp-numbers are much more relaxed.

Comment: @KamilCuk I guess '1Ex` could be parsed as `<digit> <identifier-nondigit> <identifier-nondigit>`, since preprocessing-numbers may contain nondigit identifiers. However, I think the example of `1Ex` doesn't really answer the question, if the preprocessor would have parsed it as `1` (integer-constant) `Ex` (identifier), the result would still not have been valid in later stages (an integer cannot be followed immediately by an identifier).

Comment: `f the preprocessor would have parsed it as 1 (integer-constant) Ex (identifier)` and the text follows `...token), even though a parse as the pair of preprocessing tokens 1 and Ex might produce a valid expression (for example, if Ex were a macro defined as +1).`

Comment: What does it mean to "restrict preprocessing-numbers"? If I write `#define NUM 0x2x3` and then `#if NUM == NUM`, I get an error because it's not a valid constant that can be used in an expression. If you don't parse it as a pp-num, will you still produce that error?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry if I were unclear, what I mean is basically changing the preprocessing-number token to only parse integer and floating constants. In your example, my preprocessor would not be able to tokenize the `#define`-line because `0x2x3` would not be a valid integer or floating constant. In a regular preprocessor, the `#define`-directive would not error, but the subsequent `#if`-directive would, because it internally runs the regular tokenizer on the controlling expression (`0x2x3 == 0x2x3`) to be able to evaluate it as the runtime would.

Comment: Yes. So the point is, if it "would be valid for the preprocessor to restrict preprocessing-numbers to only valid integer and floating point constants" then `1Ex` would be improperly parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly valid programs which include pp-numbers not convertible to an integer or float. The common case is a preprocessing token which does not become a token.

For example, it might be stringified:

```
#define STRINGIFY_(X) #X
#define STRINGIFY(V)  STRINGIFY_(V)
#define VERSION 3.4.6a
#define PROGNAME foo

int main(void) {
  printf("%s-%s\n", STRINGIFY(PROGNAME), STRINGIFY(VERSION));
}
```

Moreover, the version number in the above example could have been produced with token concatenation, another way preprocessing tokens never become program tokens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STRINGIFY_(X) #X
#define STRINGIFY(V)  STRINGIFY_(V)
#define CONCAT3_(x,y,z) x##y##z
#define CONCAT3(x,y,z) CONCAT3_(x,y,z)
#define CONCAT_V(mj, mn, pl) CONCAT3(mj, ., CONCAT3(mn, ., pl))

#define MAJOR 3
#define MINOR 4
#define PATCH 6a

#define VERSION CONCAT_V(MAJOR, MINOR, PATCH)
#define PROGNAME foo

int main(void) {
  printf("%s-%s\n", STRINGIFY(PROGNAME), STRINGIFY(VERSION));
}
```

There are other ways for a pp-number (or any other preprocessing token) to never be converted to a token:

1. As the argument to a macro which does not use the corresponding parameter in its replacement text.
2. In program text in a preprocessor conditional whose controlling expression is false.

   This is often used "in the wild" by to hide not-completely written code inside an `#if 0` … `#endif` block; the excluded code may have almost arbitrary syntax errors, as long as comments and strings are terminated, included invalid pp-numbers and even stray punctuation. (`@` is a valid preprocessing token which cannot be converted to a token.)

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't consider concatenation and stringification, but that's absolutely true.

Comment: @Loovjo Is that really a problem? If you parse them as tokens rather than pp-numbers, you'll still be able to stringify them.

Comment: @Barmar: Then consider the token concatenation of the pp-number `0x` with the identifier `DEADBEEF`. The concatenation is a valid number. (Or, for that matter, the concatenation of `0x` with `123CAD`.)

Comment: @loovjo: By the way, I've always read that line in the standard to mean that if the (complicated) syntax for numbers were changed, the preprocessor would still work. As it turns out, though, the changes have required changes in the preprocessor, such as adding another case for "letters which can be followed by a sign", or the extremely unfortunate (imho) change to C++ which allows `'` to be used as a thousands separator. (`_` wouldn't have required changes in the preprocessor, and tool changes would have been simpler than having to figure out when an apostrophe is not a quote.)